How to fetch column data having character varying[] column type in postgre sql?
|         Column A         |
      character varying[]
| ------------------------ | 
| {value1,value2,value3}   | 

Tried with select * from some_table where columnA LIKE '%value1%' but it returns error.
Then tried filtering expected value by using select columnA from some_table but now it returns nothing.

You are using a string function on an array value, that is not going to work. Read Array functions.

You should to use = ANY(array) predicate
(2024-07-23 06:59:40) postgres=# select * from foo;
┌───────────────────────────┐
│             a             │
╞═══════════════════════════╡
│ {value1,value2,value3}    │
│ {value10,value20,value30} │
└───────────────────────────┘
(2 rows)

(2024-07-23 06:59:55) postgres=# select * from foo where 'value1' = any(a);
┌────────────────────────┐
│           a            │
╞════════════════════════╡
│ {value1,value2,value3} │
└────────────────────────┘
(1 row)

See related doc https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html

If you want to use indexes, you'd query like this:
SELECT ...
FROM some_table
WHERE columna @> ARRAY['value1'];

The index would be
CREATE INDEX ON some_table USING gin (columna);

